# Loading multiple video players with a seekto link

Tags: video, youtube-api

I need to load 2 videos with a seekto link for both those videos.

I can do this for one video with this code:

```
     <div id="player"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);    
    var player;    
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '321',
            width: '530',
            videoId: 'IZ4uxjWUmtY',
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 0,
                rel: 0,                 
            },
            events: {
                //'onReady': onPlayerReady
                //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }    
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }    
    var done = false;    
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }    
    function seekTo(secondes) {
        player.seekTo(secondes);
    }
</script>
<a class="conseil" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="seekTo('0');">Link1</a>
<a class="conseil" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="seekTo('605');">Link2</a>
```

I don't know how to load 2 videos with a seekto link. Does anybody else know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different `player` for each videos :

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);    
var player;    
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '321',
        width: '530',
        videoId: 'IZ4uxjWUmtY',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            rel: 0,                 
        },
        events: {
            //'onReady': onPlayerReady
            //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '321',
        width: '530',
        videoId: 'IZ4uxjWUmtY',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            rel: 0,                 
        },
        events: {
            //'onReady': onPlayerReady
            //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });

}    
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}    
var done = false;    
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
    }
}    
function seekToPlayer1(secondes) {
    player.seekTo(secondes);
}
function seekToPlayer2(secondes) {
    player.seekTo(secondes);
}
```

Link1
Link2

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help your code is ok but i need to use it with a slider on this page : [link]http://www.webvideoproduction.fr/vyet10.html the first player is loaded but not the second without the slider script the 2 players are loaded, an idea ? Thanks

Comment: @Laurent create a live example with jsfiddle plz

Comment: ok http://jsfiddle.net/94150148/vb7ecrxh/ but now the first video is not loades !
Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello @mpgn, do you think it is possible that when you click on a link seekto this automatically stops playback of the video from another player? Thank you